# How to do indexing in liferay

Tags: java, liferay

i have my own custom group portlet, while creating a group we can add description about the group. My problem is when we create a group in public diffusion, and trying to search that group through description details. search is not dispalying that group in result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're modifying the behavior of a Liferay model you can use the `IndexerPostProcessor` to add additional items to the index (among other things).

See the [official Liferay documentation](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/extending-the-indexer-post-processor-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-10-en) on how to do so.

Comment: Thank you Ryan Park :) Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Even liferay blog [here](https://www.liferay.com/en_GB/web/jonas.yuan/blog/-/blogs/indexer-post-processor-hook-in-liferay-6-1) provides details about customizing indexing.